# AWS RDS mysql remote access

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, rds

guys,

I got a problem when trying to access mysql on RDS of AWS, I believe everything is ok because it works several days ago, I connected with EC2 by SSH, and input command like this: mysql -h xxxx.xxx.com -P 3306 -u xxxx -p, when I entered the password, it stuck, after a while, I got an error: **ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'xxxx.xxx.com' (110)**

I googled it, and it seemed this was a time out error, I checked the configuration of the DB instance, and belived everything was OK, what confused me most was that it always worked before, I searched all tings I can found, but still could not get it out.

Very appreciated if any one can give me some help.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you have mentioned you were able to connect few days ago and when you try to reconnect again today it is getting failed. Assuming the entire system is in place without any change; there is a high possibility that your Public IP provided by your ISP has changed and you have opened the SG for the RDS for a specific IP ( previous / Old IP )

You fix this by updating the SG with open access to your current IP or enable 0.0.0.0/0 - open to internet ( not recommended )

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, indeed, I already add the 0.0.0.0/0 to the RDS SG, unfortunately, it did not work, what wondered me most is that when I added the ip of other EC2 in the SG, I can connected to the DB, but when I connected the EC2 that contained the RDS, I could not connect it, any idea?

thanks again for your help.

Best regards Beyond Wang

Comment: Can you clarify whether you are running DB in a EC2 instance or using RDS ?

Comment: It runs in RDS which services for an EC2 instance.